# Creating a bootable USB-stick on OS X for PC

Tags: boot, usb

I am currently using a Mac running el Capitan but have now built my very first computer. I intend to use Ubuntu 16.04 as my OS.

My question is what i need to do in order to create a bootable USB, using my current OS, with which i can boot my new computer.

The internet is a vast place and the question has surely been asked before but i have not managed to find any answers. I'd be very thankful for any help.

Comment: Canonical has instructions using `unetbootin`: http://www.ubuntu.com/download/desktop/create-a-usb-stick-on-mac-osx . Any guide that uses `dd` to create the bootable USB stick will also work on Mac OS X (this is how I create mine)

Answer (score 0):

Well to create a Bootable USB of Ubuntu 16.04  in MAC , I recommend you to install [Unetbootin software](https://unetbootin.github.io) where Mac version is available. Kindly install it and download the Xenial 16.04 iso from ubuntu webpage and burn it to your USB. Not that you will be running unetbootin with privileges so , beware selecting correct USB drive if you have multiple USBs mounted simultaneously.